# How to reference a click_event for multiple buttons on a generic.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, calendar

I have a generic.Xaml theme to create a custom calendar control, which is in another project, referenced to my main WPF form. On this generic page, every day/square on the calendar has been set-up as a button. I want to add a click_event to each button, which will then trigger a method on the form that I have put the calendar control onto.

Here is the calendar:

[image: Each square is a button.]

And then the XAML code:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Click="" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" Height="72" Width="131">
                                                    <Button.Template>
                                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                                            <ContentPresenter
                                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                                                    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
                                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}, ConverterParameter=DAY}"  Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Margin="5,5,5,5" FontWeight="Light" >
                                                                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTargetMonth}" Value="false">
                                                                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                                                </Style>
                                                                            </TextBlock.Style>
                                                                        </TextBlock>
                                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </ContentPresenter.Content>
                                                            </ContentPresenter>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Button.Template>
                                                </Button>
```

As you can see from the code, I have left the click_event empty, as that is what I need assistance on, as I am unsure what is needed to reference the method in the other project. I have tried simply putting the method name in and this is the error I received:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2B0e.jpg

The method I want to link to (which will open another form):

```
  private void Day_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CalendarExtension CE = new CalendarExtension(DateTime.Now, _loggedInUser);
        CE.Show();
    }
```

**My question, as the title states, is what is the best method to reference a Click_Event from a Generic.xaml page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the old *How do I handle an event for a control declared in `generic.xaml`*' question again. Well, it's a bit of a pain frankly. You need to implement the [`Control.ApplyTemplate` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.applytemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in your `CustomControl` which is called when the `ControlTemplate` is applied.

In this method, you'll then need to access the relevant UI elements (it helps if you name them) and programmatically add your event handlers. You can take a look at the [How to: Find ControlTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN to help you access the UI elements from the `ControlTemplate`. I'm guessing that you'll be able to attach the handlers on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help. That should be all I needed to know, I'll try work the rest out from here. I'll comment if I need further assistance.

Comment: Hi again, what would I set the `TargeType` of the button `ControlTemplate` as, considering it is in another project under the same solution. The namespace of the other project is _PersonnelTracker_

Comment: If you're defining a `ControlTemplate` for a `Button`, then the `TargetType` should be `Button`. However, I really think that your requirements point to a `ToggleButton`... a `Button` that will stay selected. It might even be better using `RadioButton`s (depending on your requirements) because only one can be selected at once at each selection takes care of removing the selection of the last selected `RadioButton`.